# List what plugins are in use in my scripted Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to determine what plugins, if any, are currently being used in a  number of scripted Jenkins Pipelines, is there a programmatic way to determine this information, or am i going to need to go through every pipeline to look for calls to plugins?

I found this article, but it states that this does not cover pipelines.
https://cruftex.net/2015/11/30/Jenkins-Analyze-Your-Plugin-Usage.html

This article also points to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31582
which is stated as resolved, but I don't see API documentation on how to get this information still.

The version of Jenkins I'm using is 2.46.1

Answer (score 3):

> This article also points to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31582 which is stated as resolved, but I don't see API documentation on how to get this information still.

This was added to [Workflow-API](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-api-plugin) plugin, meaning if you would have a job, with name lets say `test`, you can get some more result by visiting the following address: `http://your_jenins/job/test/12/api/json?pretty=true`. Where `12` should be the job number you are interested with. This plugin is poorly documented though.

The part you are interested in was added to `actions`. For example, in my case:

```
_class  "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun"
actions 
0   
_class  "hudson.model.CauseAction"
causes  
0   {…}
1   {}
2   {}
3   {}
4   {}
5   
_class  "org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.RestartDeclarativePipelineAction"
6   {}
7   
_class  "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"
8   {}
9   {}
10  {}
artifacts   []
```